# Regular Expression Question

Tags: python, regex, string

I'm trying to use regular expression to extract the comments in the heading of a file.

For example, the source code may look like:

```
//This is an example file.
//Please help me.

#include "test.h"
int main() //main function
{
  ...
}
```

What I want to extract from the code are the first two lines, i.e.

```
//This is an example file.
//Please help me.
```

Any idea?

Comment: How is the "heading of a file" defined? Does it consist of all commented lines until the first uncommented line? Or until the first `include` (which might not always exist)? Do empty lines mark the end of the heading? Are spaces or tabs before the `//` allowed? Are other kinds of comments `/* */` allowed?

Answer (score 5):

Why use regex?

```
>>> f = file('/tmp/source')
>>> for line in f.readlines():
...    if not line.startswith('//'):
...       break
...    print line
...
```

Comment: Regexp should be a *last* resort. In my experience, 95% of the regexp use I've seen can be simplified in a way similar to the one Stephen presents here.

Comment: The code needs to be slightly modified so that it doesn't exit if the first line was uncommented, or if comment lines have more than one line in between them.

Comment: Line starts with "     //" ... egad.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> code="""//This is an example file.
... //Please help me.
...
... #include "test.h"
... int main() //main function
... {
...   ...
... }
... """
>>>
>>> import re
>>> re.findall("^\s*//.*",code,re.MULTILINE)
['//This is an example file.', '//Please help me.']
>>>
```

If you only need to match continuous comment lines at the top, you could use following.

```
>>> re.search("^((?:\s*//.*\n)+)",code).group().strip().split("\n")
['//This is an example file.', '//Please help me.']
>>>
```

Comment: This will give all comment lines in the file.  It won't extract just the heading.

Comment: @Stephen, I've added another regex for that.

Answer (score 1):

this doesn't just get the first 2 comment lines, but mulitline and `//` comments at the back as well. Its not what you required though.

```
data=open("file").read()
for c in data.split("*/"):
    # multiline
    if "/*" in c:
       print ''.join(c.split("/*")[1:])
    if "//" in c:
       for item in c.split("\n"):
          if "//" in c:
             print ''.join(item.split("//")[1:])
```

Comment: It does not make sense for me, why only first 2 lines, anyway +1

Answer (score 0):

to extend the context into below considerations

1. spaces in front of //...
2. empty lines between each //... line

---

```
import re

code = """//This is an example file.    
 a
   //  Please help me.

//  ha

#include "test.h"
int main() //main function
{
  ...
}"""

for s in re.finditer(r"^(\s*)(//.*)",code,re.MULTILINE):
    print(s.group(2))

>>>
//This is an example file.    
//  Please help me.
//  ha
```